# ArrayObject::offsetUnset advances the internal pointer in an unexpected way

Tags: php

Hey guys i've the following scenario

```
$col = new ArrayObject();

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    $objItem = new stdClass;
    $objItem->someVar = $i;
    $col->append($objItem);
}
```

Now i want to remove some key via `offsetUnset` and did the following

```
foreach($col AS $key => $objItem)
{
    if ($key == 2)
    {
        $col->offsetUnset($key);
    }
    echo $key.'\n';
}
```

The funpart now is the unexpected output

```
0
1
2
4
```

For a better illustration - if you put a continue in like

```
foreach($col AS $key => $objItem)
{
    if ($key == 2)
    {
        $col->offsetUnset($key);
        continue;
    }
    echo $key.'\n';
}
```

the output is

```
0
1
4
```

I never ever would've thought it bypasses the `key` number `3` in this `ArrayObject` just because i removed the previous item - it looks like the internal pointer was incremented twice or something like that...

Keep in mind i also tried something like

```
$it = $col->getIterator();

foreach($it AS $key => $objItem)
{
    if ($key == 2)
    {
        $col->offsetUnset($key);
    }
    echo $key."\n";
}
```

the output is the same

Question:

> Is this a normal behavior or do i overlook something crucial here?

pS: As nigel Ren pointed out this as a possible duplicate of [Php, Spl, ArrayIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409990/php-spl-arrayiterator), i've to point out i was looking here for an ArrayObject solution and didn't found any (i now know the ArrayIterator problem is probably the same) - but i would've never guessed that those are related to each other - in this respect i plead for not closing this question because it might help others too

Comment: please share any live demo ?

Comment: Check `var_dump($col);`  and you will see that's it's not an issue, its working as expected (indexes start from 0 so key ==2 represent the third value of the array)

Comment: @AlivetoDie my arrayobject contains 5 values - key value 2 is the third element but i dont get the 4th element with key value 3 after removing key value 2 ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php, Spl, ArrayIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409990/php-spl-arrayiterator)

Comment: @NigelRen i'll check it - but keep in mind i was looking here for an `ArrayObject` solution and didn't found any (i now know the ArrayIterator problem is probably the same) - but i would've never guessed that those are related to each other - in this respect i plead for not closing this question because it might help others too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this Bug is actually pretty simple and was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409990/php-spl-arrayiterator#answer-42554642)
by a user called Tsounabe.

I'm putting here his solution - only with one change - he was referring to an `ArrayIterator` and i was talking about an `ArrayObject` - but both are using the same function `getArrayCopy`

```
foreach($col->getArrayCopy() AS $key => $objItem)
{
    if ($key == 2)
    {
        $col->offsetUnset($key);
        continue;
    }
    echo $key.'\n';
}
```

Conclusion

> The only satisfying solution here in order to avoid this bug is the use of `getArrayCopy()` which is documented on the official PHP Site under https://secure.php.net/manual/de/arrayobject.getarraycopy.php

Answer (score 0):

In your code it is resetting object `key` after `$col->offsetUnset($key);` and continue with next key `3` after resetting it would the element whose `->someVar` value is `4`, that's why you get this output.

So you can simply use another iteration to print your object. it would work.

[Live demo](https://eval.in/993723)

Out put

```
0
1
3
4
```

Comment: can you share a live demo as I did ?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34e0f22b02d22bb174d72cc962c4535c856a941f

Comment: if you put a `continue` after the `offsetUnset` as you did - you'll see it skips 2 keys

Comment: Use another iteration to print, It seems `offsetUnset` resetting `keys` and continue to next index.

Comment: In your live example : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4a4abb9583602e4b886d598c2b7c5db2fc34298a

Comment: yeah in matter of fact this is what i did - but to be honest it doesn't solve the problem, because i didn't expect this kind of behavior, and i dont think i should - it took about 90 minutes in a very complex scenario to find out that this isn't a bug of mine ...